# Text input to act as focus

Tags: jquery

I have a function that executes when I click withing a text field.

```
$('#myField').focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == default_text) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val(default_text);
    }
});
```

However, I have another script that places cursor inside that field on page load and you can simply start typing, but when that happens my functionality doe not kick in. How can I add that initial typing input to act as .focus?

Comment: what is doing the "another script"? Post relevant code please. BTW, is this script called before you are setting focus handler?

Comment: It basically removes default text. I've updated the code.

Comment: I was talking about this: `I have another script that places cursor inside that field`

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to need to refactor a bit.

```
$('#myField').on('focus blur keyup', function(e){
    if($(this).val() == default_text && e.type == 'focus')
        $(this).val('');
    else if($(this).val().length == 0 && e.type != 'keyup')
        $(this).val(default_text);
});
```

that should do the trick

Comment: i added event type filtering that should work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/b6Dgu/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate the 'on focus' on document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myField').trigger('focus');
});
```